# Linq datetime compare in where clause

Tags: c#, linq

I have a table with a couple of columns called Key and Value.
One of the Keys is called RequestedOn and the value is a timestamp saved as a string.

Now in my linq query I would like to compare this timestamp, for example

```
var startDate = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-7);
var endDate = DateTime.Now;
var query = (from ep in db.ExtendedProperties
            where
                ep.Key == "RequestedOn" && ep.Value >= startDate && ep.Value <= endDate
            select ep).ToList();
```

Now I know I cannot compare ep.Value (string) against startDate or endDate, and I cannot convert ep.Value to a DateTime as it couldn't make sense. Any ideas on a solution?

Thanks in advance?

Comment: Why wouldn't converting to DateTime make sense? Have you tried DateTime.Parse()? Or maybe you can convert the ep.Value to string

Comment: Ideas? How about converting one of the two incompatible types to the other type?

Comment: If you need to use it inside the query then you can try to cast `startDate` and `endDate` to strings and try to use alphabetical sorting, but it depends on the format of the timespans in the DB. If you filter out data that are already in memory (`IEnumerable`) then it's better to convert dates `DateTime`. What is the format of your timespans in the database?

Comment: You should specify what ORM you are using. Everyone here seems to assume that you query an IEnumerable and can just use DateTime.Parse which I suspect is not supported in your specific LINQ provider

Comment: You should refactor your database so that your date value is an actual date data type, not a string representation of a date.

Answer (score 0):

if its saved as string you must parse it to `DateTime` and then compare

Answer (score 0):

You can either:

- Convert the DateTime to string
- Convert the string to DateTime
- Write a method that compares the 2 directly
- Something else

Comment: How do you intend to determine which of two date time *strings* occurs chronologically before another?

Comment: I don't know what these strings look like, but if they look like "2014-05-23" than you can compare them. Otherwise you need to write some comparer

Comment: There are many, many, many ways of writing out a date as a string.  Very few of them will happen to correspond with lexicographic ordering.  Writing a comparer isn't an option when the code needs to be translated into a SQL query.  SQL doesn't have custom string comparers.

Answer (score 0):

Using LINQ for something that does not have a type and contains different data is not a good option. The whole point of LINQ is to have types.

That being said one solution to your problem is to save the date in a format that is comparable as string such as 201405231801 (being 23.05.2014 18:01) and just compare strings.

Of course you care about timezones and daylight saving time you are guaranteed to get it wrong.

Answer (score 0):

If you save your strings right you can actually do a comparison:

For example: '20131201125959': year, month, date, hours, minutes, seconds.